# Error messages not showing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

for some reason my validation error messages are not showing on the window. does it have any to do with twitter-bootstrap? I remember seeing some video tutorial, but cannot find it now unfortunately.

_form partial of record

```
<%= form_for [@estate,@record] do |f| %>
      <% if @record.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@record.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this record from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @record.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    .......
    ......
    ...
    <% end %>
```

my record model

```
validates :E1, presence: true
      validates :E2, presence: true
      validates :E3, presence: true
      validates :E4, presence: true
      validates :R1, presence: true
      validates :R2, presence: true
      validates :R3, presence: true
      validates :R4, presence: true
      validates :Year, presence: true
      validate :validation
```

the create and update method of the controller

```
def create
        @record = @estate.records.build(params[:record])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @record.save
            format.html { redirect_to [@estate,@record], notice: 'Record was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @record, status: :created, location: @record }
          else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @record.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PUT /records/1
      # PUT /records/1.json
      def update
        @record = Record.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @record.update_attributes(params[:record])
            format.html { redirect_to [@estate,@record], notice: 'Record was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          else
            format.html { render action: "edit" }
            format.json { render json: @record.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

does it have anything to do that record belongs to estate and estate has many records. like while creating a record i do " @record = @estate.records.build(params[:record])"
I tried debugging it using debugger, I found out that when creating a record it is not going into the else part, it is directly creating a record without checking for the validations from the record model.

Comment: bootstrap should make no difference, it's just an aesthetic library

Comment: can you help me with the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this gem http://rubygems.org/gems/dynamic_form

It will display validation errors for you in your view. You could then delete your code looping on your instance errors.

Also, nothing to do with your issue here, but I suggest refactoring your code with the following:

in your controller:

```
respond_to :html, :json

def create
  @record = @estate.records.build(params[:record])
  if @record.save
    # flash[:success]... or whatever
  else
    # flash[:alert]... or whatever
  end

  respond_with @record
end

# same for your update method
```

For your information you can replace `render action: 'new'` by `render :new`